# Why do we select minimum size of run as a power of 2 in Timsort?

Tags: sorting, timsort

I was reading about [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). I came across the following sentence

> Minrun is chosen from the range 32 to 64 inclusive, such that the size of the data, divided by minrun, is equal to, or slightly less than, a power of two.

Why do we keep minimum run size as a power of 2? Is there any special optimization that takes place internally if we choose such a size? Please help me out.

Comment: There is a reference to the source code after that sentence. The comment there says: "Picking *some* power of 2 is important here, so that the merges end up perfectly balanced (see next section)."

Comment: Assuming this is an optimized Timsort, that alternates the direction of merge (between original and temp array) with each pass, then minrun should be chosen so that the size of data divided by min run is <= an even power of two, for an even number of passes, so that the final merge is from the temp array back to the original array, avoiding a copy pass.